# D2K Forms and reports

Tags: sql

Can any one tell me Where can i get good material to study forms and reports in oracle.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.prenhall.com/oracle/tutorial/index.html

http://www.geekarticles.com/article/Tutorial-Oracle-Designer-2000-and-Developer-2000.html

http://www.intelligentedu.com/free_oracle_training.html

are some starter links